# Python local variable modified but isn't shown at the end

Tags: python, if-statement, local-variables

```
a = 'file'
b = 'file'
c = 4
d = 4
e = 5
f = 6

def sim(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    s = 0
    if( a == b):
        s+=1
        print(s)
    if( c==d ):
        s+=1
        print(s)
    if (e == d):
        s+=1
        print(s)
    score = s/3
    return score

>>> sim(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

Output for the above is:

```
1
2
0
```

This means although s is updated at first if clauses, when it is accessed in score variable, it has the old value of s, which is 0. Can someone please explain how to correct this? Why doesn't the correct value of s is not shown to score variable

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing integer division, which will round down.

Try `2/float(3)`

Comment: I modified it to "score = s/float(3)"  . Now it works

Answer (score 7):

The `0` that is being printed isn't the value of s.  What is being printed is the return value of the function.  Python 2 uses integer division by default, so you are printing the value of `s/3`, which is `0`.

It is printing the return value of the function because you are working on the shell.  If you were running this as a separate program, it would not be printed.

Your case is very similar to this:

```
>>> def f(x):
    return x / 3

>>> f(2)
0
```

You can see, the value returned by the function is being printed.  Also, dividing 2 by 3 gives 0 with integer division.

Comment: I didn't know python used integer division, I used "s/float(3)" and now it works

Answer (score 3):

In python 2.x, if you try to divide two ints with `/`, it will actually find the floor of the two numbers (2/3=0). If you want normal division, one of the numbers should be a float. In your program, for example, you can quickly and easily fix this by writing `/3.0` instead of `/3`.

In python 3.x, `/` always means normal division and `//` is integer division/floor.

Answer (score 2):

You're using python 2, which, when one integer is divided by another then integer division is done. `2 / 3` is equal to `0` as `2 == (3 * 0) + 2`. To perform true division try:

```
score = s / 3.
```

The `.` forces the 3 to be parsed as a float. If not dividing by a literal use `float`.

```
numbers = range(10)
average = sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))
```

Or, to force true division throughout the file do:

```
from __future__ import division 
# The above must be the very first line of file, as it is not a true import, but a 
# directive to the compiler.

s = 2
score = s / 3
```